# How are the position of elements derived from the CSS attribute justify-content:space-between calculated?

Tags: c#, css, vector

This is somewhat a point of curiosity and somewhat something I actually need to use.

How are the position for of the elements derived from *justify-content:space-between* calculated?

As in this here: https://jsfiddle.net/qrjot0bh/1/

I know how to divide a line segment up with 2 Vectors, Lerping similar to this:

```
//C#
using System.Numerics;
...

int amount = 3; // element amount
float startSpace = 100; //starting X
float endSpace = 900;  //end space
Vector2 vec2Start = new Vector2(startSpace);  //vector Start
Vector2 vec2End = new Vector2(endspace);    //vector End
Vector2[] arrPossibles = new Vector2[amount];

float divider = 1f / (float)amount;
float linear = 0f;

      for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
          {
            if (i == 0)
              linear = divider / 2;
            else
              linear += divider;

            arrPossibles[i] = Vector2.Lerp(vec2Start, vec2End, linear);
          }

//...go through possibilities, treating them as center points for a prospective rectangle.
```

This is a JavaScript equivalent: https://jsfiddle.net/8c9rdejx/6/

But as you can see it's not 'between', the first and last elements are not and the start and end of the respective parent holder.

Comment: I don't understand why the p5.js equivalent is relevant. Perhaps you could explain more? This https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content gives more detail of space-between. Basically the system finds what space is left over when all the elements have been placed then divides the available space by the number of elements minus 1.  Two adjacent elements have the same space between them as any other two adjacent elements.

Comment: Sorry part of the problem is just determining the algorithm used to create the justify-content:space-between; css attribute, sorry it's vague, I dont know of a way of clarifying it without showing the difference between the two...

Comment: Can you describe any more what isn’t clear about how space-between is determined by CSS? It’s not very complicated. Would spelling it out in a formula help?

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling and searching I've managed to come up with a simple algorithm to distribute 'Blocks' with equal distances on a horizontal axis.

**Variables**

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| amount | 3 |
| Width | 800 |
| Margin | 50 |
| blockWidth | 32 |

**Code (javascript)**

```
var amount = 3;
var width = 800;
var margin = 50;
var blockWidth = 32;

var startSpace = 0 + margin;
var endSpace = width - margin;
var distance = endSpace - startSpace; 

var minrect = blockWidth; // min size for each  block
var sumWidths = blockWidth * amount; // size if we add all the blocks together
var remWidth = distance - sumWidths; // size of the space minus the size of all blocks
var spaceBetween = remWidth / (amount-1 ); //remaining white space between blocks

//Probably a better way to initialize an array.
var pos2 = new Array(amount);
for(var i=0 ; i < amount; i++) 
    pos2[i] = margin;

var last = pos2[0]; //last positon is the first element

for(var i = 1; i < amount; i++)
{
    //sum of last posistions + (space and the blockWidth) is the new Position
    pos2[i] =  last + spaceBetween + blockWidth;

    //store the current position as the last.
    last = pos2[i];
}
```

a JS Fiddle is available here: https://jsfiddle.net/joesblog/605dzcgh/53/